# How to copy files from s3 using cli in windows ec2

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am able to copy all files from the bucket but I need only the files from one folder in a bucket.

```
Bucket name : bp-dev
Folder inside the bucket is : 

aws s3 ls s3://dev/bp_source_input/
                           PRE arch/
                           PRE emr_in/
                           PRE emr_out/
                           PRE in/
2015-04-03 09:02:33          0
2015-04-13 17:05:24   11084438 201503_nts_all.xlsx
2015-04-15 09:41:20   11084438 201503_nts_all_20150415094117721.xlsx
```

I want to copy only file **201503**_nts_all_20150415094117721.xlsx to arch but here the files which are there in the **in folder** also getting copied.

```
aws s3 cp s3://dev/bp_source_input s3://dev/bp_source_input/arch --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*%mth_cd%_%source%_all_*.xlsx"
```

copy: s3://dev/bp_source_input/201503_nts_all_20150415094117721.xlsx to s3://dev/bp_source_input/arch/201503_nts_all_2015041509411772
1.xlsx
copy: s3://dev/bp_source_input/in/201503_nts_all_**201505**16094117721.xlsx to s3://dev/bp_source_input/arch/in/201503_nts_all_2015041509
4117721.xlsx

How can I copy files forom olee folder from a bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `--recursive`, have you tried specifically copying the file?

```
aws s3 cp s3://dev/bp_source_input/201503_nts_all_20150415094117721.xlsx s3://dev/bp_source_input/arch
```

Comment: HI ,I don't know the time stamp.201503_nts_all_20150415094117721.xlsx. How to use then?

Comment: Onemore question , How can delete a folder from a bucket. I want to delete only megabrand folder.C:\Business_Panorama\nts\scripts> aws s3 rm s3://bp_source_input/emr_out/201503/ --exclude "*" --include "Mega
brandsInvalidRecords/"  --recursive .

Comment: Deleting folders: You should create a separate Question, so that other people can search on the information too.

Comment: Re Time Stamp: I don't understand your requirement. Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish, with more details, including what you've tried doing that hasn't worked?